# Filter Excel rows using Excel filter or vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop, ms-office

[image]

I have 17728 rows in this format, I need to keep only the rows containing "User active", "First Name", Last Name", "Group", "24 bit card code", and "8,16 bit card code".

Like:

User active : Yes

First Name : Pharma

Last Name : Visitor 1

...

And this for all the 17728 rows in the file.

Is there a way of doing this by rows number ?

if we took the row number 3 for "User active" and add 19 we will land on the second "User active" row.
Or is there any other solution ?

Comment: Put an auto filter on the column and filter for everything that you want to keep (or remove).

Comment: Thank you @Leviathan for your answer, but I needed to do it in vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    Dim rCnt As Integer
    Dim cCnt As Integer
    Dim Obj As Object

    xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

    For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
        For cCnt = 1 To range.Columns.Count
            Obj = CType(range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Excel.Range)
            MsgBox(Obj.value)
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

source : [To read the entire worksheet in an Excel workbook through VB.net Code](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1040)